# Not able to Resize an IImage in .NET MaUI, "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: Android.Graphics.Bitmap"

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

Purpose: I am capturing an image with camera using MediaPicker, and then trying to **resize** the image to reduce it's size. Then converting this resized image to base64 string and storing it in mongodb finally.
Issue: While converting to base64 using the function `IImage.AsBase64(ImageFormat.Png, 1)`, it's throwing exception

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: Android.Graphics.Bitmap

I am in need of a little guidance.

I tried saving the image as well as `IImage.Save(sourceStream, ImageFormat.Png, 1)` function saves the IImage to a stream as well and my idea was to use this stream to convert to base64. But this idea is also throwing the same mentioned exception. I tried to set the bool flag to false to set the dispose of the source image to false. But that also didn't work.

A snippet of the code:

[image]

```
  FileResult photo = await MediaPicker.Default.CapturePhotoAsync();
  localFilePath = String.Empty;

  if (photo != null)
  {
      // save the file into local storage
      localFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName);

      IImage image;
      using Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync();
      image = PlatformImage.FromStream(sourceStream);
      if (image != null)
      {
          Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage newImage = image.Resize(500, 400,   ResizeMode.Fit, false);
          //newImage.Save(sourceStream, ImageFormat.Png, 1);
          base64ImageString = newImage.AsBase64(ImageFormat.Png, 1);
      }
```

Comment: Firstly, you can try to get the path of the image using `Path.Combine` and then use the `var b =  File.ReadAllBytes(the_path_of_the_image)`  and finally use `Convert.ToBase64String(b)`  to convert it.

Comment: That works to get the base64 string, but image won't be resized. It will retain the original size, for me it was about 5 Mb. I want to avoid this and want to resize the image to around 1Mb of space or less.

Comment: You can use the resized the image: newImage before Converting it.

Comment: Resize not working for me. I don't know what might be the cause, but I am able to get the job done using .DownSize function.

Comment: Good job! You can post your detailed solution as this would help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Below code shows how you can take/capture a photo and downsize it to another resolution. Here I have used 400 X 400(around 200kb). The original picture was of 1440×1080 (around 5mb). After downsizing it, I am converting the image to base64 for db storing purpose. (You can use base64 to image online converter to check back the downsized image again in any browser)

```
                using (Stream sourceStream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                IImage image;
                image = PlatformImage.FromStream(sourceStream);
                if (image != null)
                {
                    Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage newImage = image.Downsize(400, 400);
                    //newImage.Save(sourceStream, ImageFormat.Png, 1);
                    if (captureProductClicked)
                    {
                        base64ImageStringProduct = newImage.AsBase64(ImageFormat.Png, 1);
                        productImageAvlbl = true;
                    }
                    else if (captureCompititorClicked)
                    {
                        base64ImageStringCompetitor = newImage.AsBase64(ImageFormat.Png, 1); ;
                        competitorImageAvlbl = true;
                    }
                }
                using (FileStream localFileStream = File.OpenWrite(localFilePath))
                {
                    await sourceStream.CopyToAsync(localFileStream);
                }
            }
```